# difference between f() and ()=>f()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm confused by this when doing event handling in javascript with ReactJS.

Is there any differences between

```
<button onClick={f()} />
```

and

```
<button onClick={()=>f()} />
```

what I know is the second one is a wrapping function that return f(), but i don't see what exactly changed there. And I do see both of them in others' code.

Comment: Nice question, I've seen a lot of people having this exact error.

Comment: I think I heard somewhere that onClicks sometimes get triggered accidentally on render if  you have an `onClick={f()}` so some people use `onClick={(event) => f(event)}` to prevent it and access `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, the first case just calls `f` at load time, which is probably not what you want unless `f` returns another function (which would be called when a click event occurs). The second is just an anonymous function wrapping `f` so that `f` is not called until the `click` event happens.

Why is the second notation useful?

If `f` takes no arguments then using

```js
<button onClick={ f } /> // note: no parentheses
```

and

```js
<button onClick={ () => f() } />
```

are pretty much equivalent. There is a slight difference between the two in that the `event` is passed to `f` in the first case and is not in the second. Technically `<button onClick={ event => f(event) }/>` would be equivalent to the first case, but this is somewhat beside the point.

However, if `f` does take some arguments (other than the `event` itself), then it's useful to use:

```js
<button onClick={ () => f(someValue) } />
```

so that `someValue` can be passed to `f` when the click event happens.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these two is the first one,

```
onClick={f()}
```

means that the return value of the `f` function will be executed on the onClick event.

Whereas the second example,

```
onClick={() => f()}
```

will execute the function `f` itself on the onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't specific to React and `onClick`. It's applicable to any case in JavaScript where a function may be expected or not.

The difference between them is that one is a function while another one may not be a function.

If the result of `f()` is not a function and a function is expected then this is a mistake, like in `onClick={f()}`.

`() => f()` is a function. If it's used where a function is not expected then this is a mistake, like in `(() => f()) + 1`